# How to serialize interface-typed members with protobuf .NET?

Tags: c#, serialization, protocol-buffers, protobuf-net

The following test fails with this error:

> "System.InvalidOperationException : No
>   suitable Default IB encoding found."

```
[ProtoContract]
public class A
{
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public IB B { get; set; }
}

public interface IB
{
}

[ProtoContract]
public class B : IB
{
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public int SomeProperty { get; set; }
}

[TestFixture]
public class TestFixture
{
    [Test]
    public void Test()
    {
        var a = new A {B = new B()};
        using (var m = new MemoryStream())
        {
            Serializer.Serialize(m, a);
        }
    }
}
```

I'm using this implementation of Protobuf.net :

http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/

Did I miss something? thanks you very much.

Answer (score 2):

That is a common feature of contract-based serializers, including `XmlSerializer`, etc (i.e. those that don't include type metadata for every object).

There are a few things that make this tricky:

- during deserialization, what type would it create for `A.B`?
- during serialization, the "what is the current object" bears little relationship to the contract

  - in particular it gets very messy if the type implements multiple interfaces

This is a scenario I want to get something working for in "v2" though (but maybe not quite for release); I'm thinking:

- either `A.B` must be non-null to start with (i.e. `A` decides the type of `A.B`), or a default implementation must be specified somewhere
- interface-based is mutually exclusive vs. inheritance; when using interfaces there can be no inheritance support
- all interface usage would be via properties, never fields (obviously)

Alternatively, and perhaps more suited to the scenario presented, we could use something like `[ProtoInclude]` to indicate the concrete types.

But within those limits I think something is possible. But not today.

Comment: Is this limitation still true if i am working out of the github repository?

Comment: @james v2 can serialize many interface based models. It has dificulty with the outermost object though